# How can get video player duration in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, video-player, flutter-video-player

How can I get video duration without

```
https://pub.dev/packages/video_player
```

package or base this player. Is there any other way?

video player duration

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ffmpeg_kit_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter).

[flutter_ffmpeg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg) is discontinued now.

Here is an example:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter/ffprobe_kit.dart';

class VideoFileDurationService {
  const VideoFileDurationService._();

  static Future<Duration> getDuration(File file) async {
    final data = await FFprobeKit.getMediaInformation(file.path);
    final media = data.getMediaInformation();
    final secondsStr = media?.getDuration();

    final milliseconds = _secondsStrToMilliseconds(secondsStr);
    if (milliseconds == null) return Duration.zero;
    return Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds);
  }

  static int? _secondsStrToMilliseconds(String? secondsStr) {
    if (secondsStr == null) return null;
    final seconds = double.tryParse(secondsStr);
    if (seconds == null) return null;
    final milliseconds = (seconds * 1000).toInt();
    return milliseconds;
  }
}
```

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ffmpeg](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_ffmpeg) package for the same, just do:

```
    class ClassName {
      final FlutterFFmpeg _flutterFFmpeg = new FlutterFFmpeg();
        ...
      void someFunction() {
        _flutterFFmpeg
            .getMediaInformation("<file path or uri>")
            .then((info) => print(info));
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the video controller :

```
VideoPlayerController _controller = VideoPlayerController.network('https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4')
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
      });

 Duration durationOfVideo = _controller.value.duration;
```

Comment: But some video URL does not get the duration in VideoController.